# Can $\|B-A\|<\|A\|$ and $A$ invertible imply $B$ invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

One of the key steps in the proof of the inverse function theorem in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (Chapter 9) is the following observation regarding linear operators:

> [image]

In this theorem, $\|\cdot\|$ is the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). In the case when $n=1$, the condition
$$
\|B-A\|\cdot\|A^{-1}\|<1\tag{1},
$$
is *equivalent* to
$$
\|B-A\|<\|A\|.\tag{2}
$$
In the case when $n\geq 2$, (2) is weaker than (1) because in general 
$$
\|A\|\geq \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.
$$

Here is my question:

> Is the theorem still true if one replace (1) by (2) in the case when $n>1$?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is diagonalisable, with distinct positive eigenvalues. And $B$ has the same eigenspaces, just with [possibly] different eigenvalues. Can you arrange it so that one of $B$'s eigenvalues is $0$, but $\lVert A - B\rVert < \lVert A\rVert$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following example?

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad\text{and}\qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

We have $\|A\| = 2$ and $\|B - A \| = 1$, but $B$ is not invertible.